# The use of "will" and "be going to" for something that will happen in the very near future

Tags: future-tense

I read in one grammar book that *will* and *be going to* can be used for something planed in the future. But if it is the very near future. For example:

> I **will** go to work tomorrow.
>
> I **am going to** go to work tomorrow.

If someone would say the first sentence what would you think? Does that sound natural? Do the two sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: Both sound natural to me, and in this particular case I don't perceive any difference in meaning at all (not even a subtle difference).

Answer (score 1):

> "I will go to work tomorrow."

You just state that because you believe it will happen tomorrow.

> "I am going to work tomorrow."

You have decided that before talking about it and now just express your intention.